# Como faço para enviar um formulario por e-mail e alterar a DIV para outra com uma mensagem?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Oie

Eu fiz seguinte:

**HTML**

```
<div id="minhaDiv">
    <form id="formulario">
        <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Digite seu Nome">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Digite seu email">
        <input type="button" id="salvar" name="salvar" value="Salvar" class="btn-toggle" data-element="#minhaDiv">
    </form>
    </div>
    <div id='msgsucess' class='output' style="display: none">
     Obrigado por entrar em contato.
    </div>
```

**JS Query**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$("#salvar").click(function (){
   var form = new FormData($("#formulario")[0]);
   $.ajax({
       url: 'recebeDados.php',
       type: 'post',
       dataType: 'json',
       cache: false,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       data: form,
       timeout: 8000,
       success: function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           el = $(this).data('element');
           $(el).toggle();
           $('#minhadiv').hide();               
           $('#mgssucess').show();
       }
   });
});
});
```

Arquivo em PHP **recebeDados.php**

```
$nome  = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: site@teste.com.br\r\n"; // remetente
$headers .= "Return-Path: site@teste.com.br\r\n"; // return-path
$envio = mail("site@teste.com.br", "$nome", "$email", $headers);
```

Ele apaga a div `minhaDiv`, mas não mostrou a outra

Answer (score 1):

É simples, a div tem o seguinte id:
`id='msgsucess'`
e seu código está assim:
`$('#mgssucess').show();`
basta mudar para:
 `$('#msgsucess').show();`

Comment: Nossa, mas eu mudei e ainda não aparece a div com a mensagem

Comment: o que tem na classe output no seu CSS? tentou inspecionar o `html` e ver se a `div` está mesmo oculta?

Comment: nao tem css, sim esta aparecendo oculta

Comment: fiz um exemplo aqui (tirando a chamada Ajax) que está funcionando perfeitamente: https://jsfiddle.net/8b1fw88y/1/

Comment: note que no seu exemplo essa linha `$('#minhadiv').hide();` está errada também, já que o `Javascript` é case sensitive, deveria estar assim:  `$('#minhaDiv').hide(); `

Answer (score 1):

Seu código não funcionará pois `e.preventDefault();` é inválido. No momento que você tentar executar essa função, o navegador irá dar erro e parar a execução do restante do código.

Outro erro é que `$(this)` retorna a função em que ele foi chamado, ou seja, `$(this).data('element');` também é inválido, pois ele está sendo chamado dentro de `success` e portanto, `$(this)` retorna `success`.

Nesse erro, ele não irá parar a execução, mas é sempre bom corrigir.

Além disso, o *ID* dos elementos são inválidos.

**Código correto:**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#salvar").click(function (){
       var form = new FormData($("#formulario")[0]);
       $.ajax({
           url: 'recebeDados.php',
           type: 'POST',
           dataType: 'json',
           cache: false,
           processData: false,
           contentType: false,
           data: form,
           timeout: 8000,
           success: function(e){
                $('#minhaDiv').hide();               
                $('#msgsucess').show();
           },
           error: function(err) {
               alert( err.responseText )
           }
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, mas agora não faz nada só envia o email, acho que vou fazer um modal com mensagem, pelo menos isso eu consigo fazer

Comment: Se possível abra o console (F12) e verifica se há algum erro.

Comment: Abrir não aparece nada, e se eu tirar do success ?

Comment: @Junior editei minha resposta. Adicione o `callback` de erro.

Comment: Legal, Aparece uma janela sem nada escrito e um botao de ok. Acho que isso deve estar no lugar errado  $('#minhaDiv').hide();               
                $('#msgsucess').show();

Comment: @Junior é sinal que seu código em `recebeDados.php` está com um erro e não está conseguindo ser executado. Por isso não está retornando o callback `success`. O código não está no lugar errado, o que está errado é o código do arquivo supracitado.

Comment: Coloquei o código do recebeDados.php